# validate form inputs bootstrap4

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have this code in my vue template

```
        <div class="form-row" :class="{'was-validated': this.checkPassword()}">
          <div class="col-6">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" class="form-control" ref="password" required v-model="password">
            <div class="valid-feedback" v-if="!error">
              Password match
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback" v-else>
              Password not match
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <label>Confirm password</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" class="form-control" ref="passwordCheck" required v-model="passwordCheck" @change="checkPassword()">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click.prevent="copyToClipboard()"><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want to show like the bootstrap4 documentation a green input field if the password matches or a red one if the password aren't matching. I'm trying by adding the `was-validated` class to the `form-row` if the demanded method return true but when the view where the password inputs are rendered the two input fields are always red. How I can fix this to give the correct feedback to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always share all the relevant parts of the component otherwise, it's hard to tell where the problem resides. Here, you haven't shared your `<script>` section. Anyway, I guess this should put you on the right track.

```
<template>
    <div class="form-row" :class="{'was-validated': this.checkPassword()}">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label>Password</label>
            <label>
                <input :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" class="form-control" :class="getPasswordClass()"
                       ref="password" required v-model="password">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <label>Confirm password</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>
                    <input :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" class="form-control" :class="getPasswordClass()"
                           ref="passwordCheck" required v-model="passwordCheck" @input="checkPassword()">
                </label>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click.prevent="copyToClipboard()"><i
                        class="fas fa-clipboard"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            password: null,
            passwordCheck: null,
            error: true,
            showPassword: true,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        checkPassword() {
            this.error = this.password !== this.passwordCheck;
        },
        getPasswordClass() {
            if (!this.password || !this.passwordCheck) {
                return '';
            }

            return this.error ? 'is-invalid' : 'is-valid'
        },
        copyToClipboard() {
            //
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

So, in my opinion, you should only set the dynamic class (`is-valid` or `is-invalid`) when both inputs are provided. In this example I've added that to both *password* and *passwordCheck* fields but I think it's enough to just apply it to the *passwordCheck* because that's the one checked against the *password*.

---

If you only want to check after user leaves the field you could adjust the code like this:

In the template remove:

```
:class="{'was-validated': this.checkPassword()}"
```

And update:

```
@blur="checkPassword()
```

In the `data()` add:

```
blurred: false,
```

In the methods update:

```
methods: {
    checkPassword() {
        this.blurred = true;
        this.error = this.password !== this.passwordCheck;
    },
    getPasswordClass() {
        if (!this.blurred) {
            return '';
        }

        return this.error ? 'is-invalid' : 'is-valid'
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I'm referring to the [validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#validation) of bootstrap 4 not to the form input outline css

Comment: Ah I see. You should still set the dynamic class using Vue so it's not just Bootstrap. I'll update my answer to help you with that.

Comment: nice solution,I will try it. I was only binding the classes based on the checkPassword() method, but I didn't considered that it was always called before the password was checked.

Comment: If I want to provide the visual feedback when the user has finished to type into the password confirm field, is there a better way than using the `@input` ? I want also implement the `valid-feedback` and `invalid-feedback` messages after the `is-valid` or `is-invalid` classes are added, can you give me some tips about? PS: I0ve tested your implementation and works fine :)

Comment: I think you're looking for `@blur`? I'll add some additional snippet to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Very helpful and works fine. I'm not a front-end expert so many things related to data presentation aren't really in my main focus!